# why is scanf causing infinite loop when entering a char different than number?

Tags: c, scanf, infinite-loop

```
int main()
{
    int choose, isNum;
    printf("Choose 1,2,3,4,5,6\n");
    isNum = scanf("%d",&choose);
    while(choose != 0){
        if(!isNum || choose > 6){
            printf("Wrong option!\n");
            printf("Choose 1,2,3,4,5,6\n");
            isNum = scanf("%d",&choose);
            continue;
        }

        //6 ifs checking which number have you choose and what it does..

        printf("Choose 1,2,3,4,5,6\n");
        isNum = scanf("%d",&choose);
}}
```

I tried many things from here, fflash, cclear, and at that moment I'm checking first if its a number then using it like many of the answers suggested and it always getting back to the same infinite loop.
my question is different because I tried every answers and as I said, it didn't help, not fflush, not cclear and not checking if its a number before using it..

Comment: You should not use the variable `choose` at all before you have checked the value of `isNum`.

Comment: You need to (a) clear the input buffer of the input that is blocking the read and (b) check specifically for `isNum != 1` (instead of `!isNum`) otherwise the code will fail when `EOF` is returned. Note that `fflush` should not be used for input stream.

Answer (score 0):

That's how `scanf()` works with invalid input. I see that you check with `isNum` if proper input has been given but that `choose` in the condition is not correct. The thing is that what have you written stays in the buffer if not consumed from `scanf()`, that's what causing the infinite loop. You must write code so that the buffer is cleared, and then invoke `scanf()` again.

One solution for clearing the buffer is this piece of code: `while ((getchar()) != '\n');`

Comment: Do you mean to use the fflush(stdout); function? because I already tried it, I entered it before every scanf and it still enter the same loop.

Comment: @Asaf stdout is not the stream you must clear. It is stdin . But instead of flushing you can write this : while ((getchar()) != '\n'); and it should clear the buffer for you. It consumes whatever has remained in the buffer

Comment: thanks, fflush(stdin) works, its a school thing so I can't use getchar function but how is it different than while(choose != '\n') because that didn't work and also, why is it matter not using the fflush?

Comment: @Asaf See [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)

Comment: It is undefined behavior to use fflush(stdin). In some compilers and systems may work in some other may not. Please consider marking my answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @Asaf If you're not allowed to call `getchar` to fetch and discard the "bad" characters, then just make sure you don't type "bad" characters in the first place.  Please don't look for an excuse to call `fflush(stdin)` -- it really is a bad thing to do.  The bottom line is that `scanf` isn't a very good input function, and one of the things it's poorest at is dealing with malformed input.  If you want to write a program that deals well with malformed input, the first thing to do is not use `scanf` at all.  (And then the urge to call `fflush` doesn't even come up.)